# MySQL bi-weekly rotating workers shifts

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a view or SP to generate a table with workers' shifts in MySQL.

We have 2 shifts that rotate every week.
A worker that has worked this week in a morning shift (06h-14h), next week he will work in a afternoon shift (14h-22h).
If I set a fixed day to get a starting point, let's say that on 01/01/2021 Shift A was working a morning shift (06h-14h) and on that day Shift B worked in the afternoon shift (14h-22h).

How to create a view with populated shifts?
For example:

```
01/01/2021 (Sat)   ShiftA   AM
01/01/2021 (Sat)   ShiftB   PM
02/01/2021 (Sun)   ShiftA   AM
02/01/2021 (Sun)   ShiftB   PM
03/01/2021 (Mon)   ShiftA   PM
03/01/2021 (Mon)   ShiftB   AM
04/01/2021 (Tue)   ShiftA   PM
04/01/2021 (Tue)   ShiftB   AM

.......
```

Could maybe the MySQL Week() function be used here?

Comment: You must define some base date. Then simply check what is the reminder of the datediff between base date and current date divided by 14. When 0..6 then the timeshift is the same like the shift for base date, when 7..13 then the timeshift is opposite (or use the integer division for the reminder by 7).

Comment: show the data you have, not just the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive `cte` to build the schedule: the `cte`'s termination condition can be when the number of weeks the schedule should be is reached, and you can keep a counter along with the original shift assignments and use modulo to reassign shifts in alterating form when a new week is started:

```
with recursive cte(dt, shift, tm) as (
    select date(now()), 1, 0
    union all
    select date(now()), 2, 1 
    union all
    select c.dt + interval 1 day, c.shift, case when dayofweek(c.dt + interval 1 day) = 2 then c.tm%2 = 0 else c.tm end 
    from cte c where c.dt < now() + interval 2 week
)
select dt, shift, case when tm = 0 then 'AM' else 'PM' end from cte;
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=342570c7824176be41705f6a3da5b095).